# npm WARN Laravel errors don't allow me to have CSS implemented on my localhost

Tags: javascript, node.js, laravel, npm

This are my tailwindcss errors:

> npm WARN @tailwindcss/custom-forms@0.2.1 requires a peer of tailwindcss@^1.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

> npm WARN @tailwindcss/typography@0.2.0 requires a peer of tailwindcss@^1.5.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

> npm WARN @tailwindcss/ui@0.7.2 requires a peer of tailwindcss@^1.8.3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

Optional and not supported errors:

> npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.1.3 (node_modules\laravel-mix\node_modules\fsevents):

> npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

> npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules\fsevents):

> npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

> npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.1.3 (node_modules\webpack-dev-server\node_modules\fsevents):

> npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

A screenshot of localhost after auth:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Rbzr.png

Comment: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/laravel

Comment: I completed the steps but still nothing got fixed.

Answer (score 0):

```
 composer require laravel/ui 

 php artisan ui bootstrap --auth  

npm install
npm run dev
```